# p is prime and a group of 2p - 2 number

Tags: calculus

This is a question that I see in a book. I translate it and ask it here. my Mathematical ability is not good.

if $p$ is prime, we have $2p-2$ natural number that if we choose any $p$ of them (call S), the sum of numbers in S can not be divisible by $p$. Is below statement true?

for each $1 \le i \le p -1$ we have $p - 1$ numbers which sum of them is M and  $M\equiv i\pmod p$

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem